# How to increment Image name?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

as i was continuing to work on an application, i came across this issue an i still couldn't solve it for more than 4 days now. The issue is that i cannot increment the naming of the saved images to a certain number and then comeback to the number 0 and start overwriting those images until i reach than number again and so on repeatedly!
let me give u an example : i want to save 10 Images and i want them to be names "1.png", "2.png"......"10.png", but i want the 11th one to overwrite the "1.png", 12th to overwrite the "2.png" and so on.

i've tried multiple approaches but none of them worked! :(

here's my code, thank you :

```
QObject::connect(_image_capture.data(), &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [=] (int id, QImage img) {

QString fileName = QString::number(id)+ ".png";
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation) + "/" + fileName;
img.save(path, "PNG");

});
```

Comment: Hint: `11 % 10 == 1`, `32 % 10 == 2`, `123456 % 10 == 6`,...

Comment: If you have a `std::string s="9.png";` try to see what happens after `s[0] = ((s[0] + 1) % 10) + '0';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator (%), for example :

- 0%10=0
- 1%10=1
- ...
- 10%10=0
- 11%10=1
- ...
- 12971982%10=2

Comment: can i use this modulo operator in Qt? it doesn't seem to work when i try it

Comment: It's a c++ native operator, you can use it on any round number @Hamza

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution i've found :

```
QObject::connect(_image_capture.data(), &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [=] (int id=0, QImage img) {
        QString fileName = QString("%1.png").arg(1 + (id % 11));
        QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation) + "/" + fileName;
        img.save(path, "PNG");
        });
```

Thank you for your help and time :D